# How to overlap some parts of 2 ImageViews

Tags: android

I have 2 ImageViews, one is at the right side of other. I want to overlap %20 parts of these images.

() => First image,
[] => Second image

(  [ ) ]

Answer (score -1):

Use FrameLayout,

```
<FrameLayout
...
>
  <ImageView
  ...
  >
  <ImageView
  ...
  >
<FrameLayout>
```

ImageViews will be stacked one above the other , give appropriate positions according to your requirement

Comment: I haven't ever use FrameLayout. Thank you. I will try.